# How to pass default value of Hibernate Entity field value while saving entity

Tags: hibernate

I have **@Embeddable** class **AuditColumn.java** as below.

```
public class AuditColumn {

    @Column( name = "create_user", nullable = false )
    private String createUser = null ;

    @Column( name = "create_date", nullable = false , columnDefinition = "datetime default now()" )
    private Calendar createDate = null ;

    @Column( name = "update_user", nullable = false )
    private String updateUser = null ;

    @Column( name = "update_date", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "datetime default now()" )
    private Calendar updateDate = null ;

    public static AuditColumn getInstance( String user ) {

        AuditColumn auditColumn = new AuditColumn();

        auditColumn.setCreateUser(user);
        auditColumn.setUpdateUser(user);

        return auditColumn ;
    }
}
```

And other Class **A.java** which uses **AuditColumn.java** as **@Embedded** as below.

```
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id = -1 ;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName    = null ;

    @Column( name = "last_name" )
    private String lastName     = null ;

    @Embedded
    AuditColumn auditColumn = null ;
}
```

Trying to save the Entity A as below.

```
A a = new A();
a.setFirstName("firstName " );
a.setLastName("lastName " );

AuditColumn auditColumn = AuditColumn.getInstance("USER");      
a.setAuditColumn(auditColumn);

session.save(a);
```

On Executing above code getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.bpk.hibernate.data.model.A.auditColumn.createDate
```

Is there any way to pass the default value of CreateDate of AuditColumn without setting the value through java?

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the createDate field with @CreationTimeStamp.

```
public class AuditColumn {

@Column( name = "create_user", nullable = false )
private String createUser = null ;

@Column( name = "create_date", nullable = false , columnDefinition = "datetime default now()" )
@CreationTimestamp
private Calendar createDate = null ;

@Column( name = "update_user", nullable = false )
private String updateUser = null ;

@Column( name = "update_date", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "datetime default now()" )
private Calendar updateDate = null ;

public static AuditColumn getInstance( String user ) {

    AuditColumn auditColumn = new AuditColumn();

    auditColumn.setCreateUser(user);
    auditColumn.setUpdateUser(user);

    return auditColumn ;
}
```

}

Refer Hibernate user guide 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-hibernate-creationtimestamp

Comment: Already tried with that 
Getting below exception
SEVERE: Throwable inside Configuration.getSessionFactory ::>> Still need to wire in composite in-memory value generation

Comment: Possibly an error is thrown when getting the session factory. Did you make any change in the configuration xml . Share the complete stack trace , also the configuration xml